# MYSQL | Request from two tables 2

Tags: php, mysql, request

I have 2 Mysql tables:

A (Users table):

id       username room

```
1    User1    1 
2    User2    1
3    User3    1
```

B (Blocked users):

```
id   username
1    User3
```

My request is here (I would like to get User1 and User2 as User3 is in block):

```
SELECT A.id, A.username FROM `table1` A, `table2` B 
  WHERE A.roomid = 1 AND A.username != B.username
```

But this is wrong request.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to either `join` the two tables A&B like

```
SELECT A.id, A.username FROM `table1` A
JOIN `table2` as B ON `table1`.id = `table2`.id
WHERE A.room = 1 AND A.username != B.username
```

OR your column name is `room` not `roomid` like

```
SELECT A.id, A.username FROM `table1` A, `table2` B 
WHERE A.room = 1 AND A.username != B.username
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.id, A.username,B.id,B.username FROM `table1` A, `table2` B
WHERE A.roomid = 1 AND A.username != B.username
```

Answer (score 0):

In table A what is mean by ID? is it the id of the username?
In table B what is mean by ID?

you have to use sql join to get the expecting out put. but to do that you need a common key in both table. According to your table example I think that ID is not the common key and you just use it. but If I wrong, you can join the two tables using inner join while getting the ID as the common key.